# Hibernate function Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, hibernate, lock-screen

I ahev an ASUS Zenbook14 and I am trying to fully making it operative with Ubuntu 19.04.

Unfortunately, it ha not an "Hibernate" function, in the sense that:

1. When I cose the screen, nothing happens, and the laptop stays operative as nothing was done
2. Sometimes, when it is not plugged to power, it stuck to blank screen with no possibiliy to save the work done.

How to solve?

Comment: There is some information on this in this link: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/restore-hibernate-mode-on-ubuntu/ It's a bit complicated but if it works for you I can précis it and post as an answer for use by others.

Comment: This is not complicated but it is for suspending instead of hibernating when lid close: https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-close-lid-suspend/ Do you have this set in your settings?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but the link suggested at https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-close-lid-suspend/ is not working. I haven't the lid options in my settings and the workaround suggested is not working.. (Some comments on the linked webpage also suggest that the procedure is not working for ubuntu 18, so I guess it won't work for 19.04).

Comment: I tried to set the on/off button as 'hibernate' but it is only possible to suspend

Comment: Also the instructions reported at the link posted by @Graham are not working